# Selendroid. How can you execute a Javascript in a hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am looking for an equivalent of a webdriver commad:

```
String name = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver()).executeScript("return document.title");
```

How can i trigger this in a  hybrid app?
SelendroidDriver does not have method like executeScript.